# Can't access "rangeOfString" in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift3

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if(textField.tag==1) {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        if (!textField.text.length) {
            return NO;
        }
        if ([[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] rangeOfString:@"  "].length) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    if ([textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length < textField.text.length) {
        return YES;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

in swift 3 i have almost converted but "rangeOfString" is accessible so 
can anyone convert this Objective c to swift 3

Comment: This is Objective c code, show us what you have try in Swift 3.

Comment: i want convert this code in swift 3

Comment: This isn't a free code translation service. Please attempt the conversion yourself first. Update your question with your attempted Swift code. Explain what specific issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Convert Objective c to Swift 3 here. Good luck!

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(textField.tag == 1) {
        let nsString = textField.text as NSString?
        var newString = nsString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if(string == " "){
            if(textField.text!.characters.count < 1){
                return false;
            }

            if (newString != nil && newString!.range(of: "  ") != nil){
                    return false;
            }
        }

        if(newString != nil && newString!.characters.count < textField.text!.characters.count){
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```